# Does including php-pear in a Dockerfile automatically force install of latest PHP version?

Tags: php, docker, version, pear, pecl

I'm specifically installing `PHP 8.1` in Dockerfile, on quite a few lines.  Now, I've also added a line to install `php-pear` (for `PECL`), but it seems to automatically bump up PHP to `8.2`.  And in the container you can see both `8.1` AND `8.2` installed.  CLI is set to 8.2.

Can't you peg `php-pear` to `8.1`?

I tried installing `php8.1-pear`, and `php8-pear`, but no such packages exist.  I do not want PHP 8.2 installed, but `php-pear` seems to require, or force, it.